# Gettig Blank IMEI Using Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I am Trying to getting IMEI num of Device using this code.
When I am Deployint my app I get blank Deviceid where as i am getting devicesoftware version correctly

```
Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
            mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);
            m_deviceId = mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
```

Answer (score 1):

from the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId())

> This method was deprecated in API level 26. Use getImei() which
> returns IMEI for GSM or getMeid() which returns MEID for CDMA.

Comment: Thanks 
But getimei() is not supported in Visual Studio
Can you explain in Detail

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.telephony.telephonymanager.imei?view=xamarin-android-sdk-9

Comment: hello sir i am beginner here,
Can you please write two lines of code for me to get better Understanding

Comment: `m_deviceId = mTelephonyMgr.Imei;`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is simple

```
Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager mTelephonyMgr;
mTelephonyMgr = (Android.Telephony.TelephonyManager)GetSystemService(Context.TelephonyService);

if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt>= BuildVersionCodes.O)
        {
            m_deviceId = mTelephonyMgr.Imei;
        }
        else
        {
            m_deviceId = mTelephonyMgr.DeviceId;
        }
```

Also make sure you have read phone state permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Comment: SIr In VS 2017  getting error telphonemanager does not confain defination for IMEI

Comment: Yes because VS 2017 is obsolete start using 2019 now